# How to send a "score" from one html. file to another using localstorage and JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, local-storage

I am quite new in the programming world and i have built up an easy soccer juggling game where I want to send the score to another file where I list up the highscores.

But I am struggling. My game is based off of many different functions that occur in one big gameLoop.

**First the user write their name:**

```
   var brukerNavn = prompt("Please write your Username");
```

**Then, in the GameLoop I have a function that "creates" the user:**

```
        function saveUser(){
            var userObj = {
            "userName": userName,
            "score": points,
        };
            var userInfo = localStorage.setItem("sendResult", JSON.stringify(userObj));
        };
```

**Here is a part of the function that checks if the ball hits the bar. This is where I get the point score from:**

```
            if(!ballToTheLeft&&!ballToTheRight&&!ballIsOver&&!ballIsOver){
                ball.ydirection = -0.5; 
                points = points +1;
                hdnPoeng.innerHTML = points;
        
            };
```

**This, for instance the whole GameLoop:**

```
        function gameLoop(){
            drawField();
            drawBall();
            drawBar();
            checkIfBallHitsTheBar();
            checkIfBallPassesTheBar();
            saveUser(); //This is the function I mentioned earlier.
            if(theGameIsOn){
                requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
            };
        };
        gameLoop();
```

The game is working fine, but I wonder how I can send the score + name to another file? If you need more of the code I am happy to share:)

Answer (score 0):

Use storage.getItem(sendResult) to access it in another file.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem

Comment: I dont need to parse it?                                                                                                          
var highscoreObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sendResult"));

Comment: I am only showing how to get it in another file.

Comment: And then I use console.log("sendResult") to check if the object has been sent over?

Comment: If you want to test if it is working, then use console.log.

Comment: Welcome! And could you upvote my answer if helpful?